# Beach Activity?

Tags: grammar, hyphens

I heard some people talking:

> Do you have a favorite **beach activity**?

If one wrote this, what would seem proper, and, maybe, grammatically perfect:

> . . . **beach activity**

or,

> . . . **beach-activity**

?

Comment: Think of it this way: *beach* is functioning as an adjective here, and we don't put a hyphen between an adjective and the noun that it modifies.  You wouldn't say "Do you have a red-towel?" or "Did you see a tall-man?", so you wouldn't use "beach-activity" here either.

Comment: Ah. I feel, like, when I maybe hear others say this, it almost sounds like it connects . . . sounding like that . . . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compound nouns](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/compound-nouns/) are common in English:

> Bed frame
>   Side order
>   Dinner service
>   Police car

and possibly tens of thousands more. In fact people frequently make them up as needed:

> Come on down to the park this Saturday for our first annual **Watermelon Jubilee**!

You won't find "watermelon jubilee" in the dictionary, but if you know a *watermelon* is a kind of fruit, and a *jubilee* is a big party, then you can assume it's a big party where lots of watermelon will be served.

Only a small percentage of compound nouns are hyphenated, usually if there is any ambiguity about what the noun means.  For example:

> *ice-axe*  vs *ice axe* (Both are acceptable, but ice-axe makes it clear that the axe is not made of ice.)

[More information](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_nouns.htm)

In your sentence, no hyphen is necessary.  *Beach activity* is perfectly natural.

Comment: I get a kick out of the fact that *ice cream* was originally *iced cream* (which actually makes more sense, although I can understand the shift due to pronunciation)—and I'm waiting to see if it ever becomes simply *icecream* at some point in the future.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think only children with unnaturally good diction have separated the words ever since it was created,  *"Icecream!  We want icecream!"*  :)

Comment: Not to be confused with *I scream!* ;)

Comment: I don't think beach activity is a compound noun. I think beach is merely used as an adjective. Work activity, leisure activity, etc.

Comment: @Lambie  I'm not tied to the definition.  Since both "beach" and "activity" are nouns, it seemed like "compound noun" was appropriate -- but If there's a more accurate term, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: @Andrew Well, I put it in my answer.

Comment: This may make most sense, using, “ . . . *makes it clear that the axe is not made of ice.*”, as a qualifier whether to hyphen, or not . . . I greatly appreciate it, Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Without the hyphen please.

> Do you have a favorite beach activity?

In the same way, we don't ask

> What are your favourite farm-animals?

but

> What are your favourite farm animals?

Answer (score 0):

- beach activity
- work activity
- leisure activity

These are all nouns used as adjectives.

Comment: Hm. I never saw *beach* used as an adjective, only noun, or, verb

Comment: It is very common in English to use nouns as adjectives. playtime activity is another. And yes, no dash.